# Two separate keypresses become combined. Bug?

Tags: laptop, drivers, keyboard, touchpad

No matter how I scroll, holding control within half-a-second of the input afterwards causes the screen to zoom in and out. This normally does not happen, so I assume there is some delay between inputs that gets mixed up with each other because releasing the input is registered late. It also happens on the keyboard using two buttons in a similar manner such as Ctrl and A, or Shift and H and then trying to press "i" but it comes out as "I".

I'm using an ASUS Touchpad driver and an ATK keyboard driver. Any possible replacements or fixes?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have sticky keys enabled by any chance?

Another possibility is sticky keys in the literal sense, i.e. a minor spill on the keyboard cause the keys to release slowly.

Does this affect both ctrl keys? Does this affect both shift keys?

Comment: This is a brand new laptop. Nothing is on.
Both buttons are affected. I assume this is an internal issue.